# Asynchronous Typescript/JavaScript and Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I am fairly new to Typescript/JavaScript.  So this probably a noob question:

I have a Typescript class, lets call it `serviceActions`.

In the `constructor` of that class I make a connection to a Web API service via BreezeJS.  I also get the metadata for service (`fetchMetadata`).

However, the `fetchMetadata` call returns a promise.  So the `constructor` returns before it is done.

Now this `serviceActions` class is injected (via Aurelia) into another class:

```
@autoinject
export class BoxVm {
    constructor(serviceActions: serviceActions) { 
        this.box = this.serviceActions.createNewBox();
    }
```

So I never really get to await anything.  So when the `createNewBox` is called, the `fetchMetadata` call is not done, and the call errors out.

Now I could put in an `initialize` method on my `ServiceActions`class.  But then I have to wrap everything I do in my BoxVM in the promise for that.  All calls to get data, save data create any entity would have to be done in a call to `initalize.then`.

**Is there another way?  Am I missing the point?  Or is this the way that Typescript/JavaScript is done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ServiceActions` is waiting for a promise to be fulfilled before it can be usable. There are several solutions:

1. Wait for ES7, which lets us `await` the results of a promise. Your `createNewBox` function will wait patiently for the promise to finish before returning. This is the cleanest solution.
2. Figure out a way to pass the results of `fetchMetadata` into the constructor (possibly making the call before running your DI framework initialization). This avoids the problem.
3. Do what you suggest with `initialize().then`, though it seems mildly error-prone (someone might forget to wrap code in init).
4. Create an `onInit` function in `ServiceActions` that takes a callback - it's a mildly refactored version of what you're suggesting.
5. Have `createNewBox` return a promise to hand over a new `Box` once `ServiceActions` is done waiting for the `fetchMetadata` promise. This might pollute everything with many promises.

I would try for option 2, especially since you seem to need to call this only once.

Comment: #1 can't work because constructors can't be asynchronous functions.

Comment: I figured out a way to make my call before Aurelia shows the UI.  (In the then of `aurelia.start().then(a => {....`)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more a question of how your framework works with dependency injection. [Syringe](https://github.com/matthewjh/Syringe#lazy-dependencies) lets you inject a "lazy" dependency, which you have to call `.get().then(callback)` on in order to use that dependency.

In general, though, yes: any time you need to use something that gets produced by an asynchronous operation, you're going to need to access it through the promise interface. This will become syntactically easier once TypeScript adds better `async/await` support, but you can't just assume you've got access to a resource for injection if that resource is produced via an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Incidentally, the `.get().then(callback)` would behave almost identically to `.initialize().then(callback)`